# Deploy SQL database into different Resource Group than SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy SQL database into different Resource Group than SQL server? It is possible to have multiple SQL servers in one Resource Group. But is it possible to have SQL server and corresponding database in different Resource Group?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking but... what issue are you having? And what led you to believe things need to be in the same resource group?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible.

You must create Azure SQL database and the Logical Sql Server into one resource group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible for now.

You must create Azure SQL database and the Logical Sql Server into one resource group.

It's not clear in official documents, However, you cannot create/move the database to different resource group from the Logical Azure SQL server.

If this is important to you, you can post your idea in [User Voice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database). The Azure Team will see it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Direct Link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/17367109-allow-database-to-reside-in-different-resource-gro